# Does autoexp.dat works in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, autoexp.dat

Is `autoexp.dat` read in Visual Studio 2015?
Note the "Enable Native Edit and Continue" is already checked in. Also I know about .natvis format. But for some reason I am asked to use `autoexp.dat`.

The rule is simple:

There is class called Person as shown below:

```
class Person
{
   int age;
   double height;
};
```

The Watch window should display in auto expand only age property of the Person and not height.

The rule entered in autoexp.bat under `[AutoExpand]` is as follows:

```
[AutoExpand]

Person =age=<;age>;
```

But its not working. The watch window in auto expand shows both age and height.

So does rules such as above are recognized in Visual Studio 2015?